# angular emoji picker not working on windows 7

Tags: javascript, angular, web, frontend, emoji

I have an angular project, In my project I used @joeattardi/emoji-button plugin to add emoji picker to my chat box

this is template

```
<form action="" class="type-message">
        <input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'meeting-side.write-message' | translate }}" id="newMessage"
            (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" [(ngModel)]="newMessage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  autocomplete="off" required>
        <div class="actions-row">
            <div class="icons-actions">
                <mat-icon id="emojiButton" matTooltip="{{'meeting-side.add-emoji' | translate}}" matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip">sentiment_satisfied_alt</mat-icon>
            </div>
            <a (click)="sendMessage()" [ngClass]="{'disabled': !newMessage}">
                {{ "meeting-side.send" | translate }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and in my component.ts code I added this code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

    let button = document.querySelector('#emojiButton') as HTMLButtonElement;
    let picker = new EmojiButton({
      autoHide: false
    });
    
    let input = document.querySelector('#newMessage') as HTMLInputElement;

    picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
      this.newMessage += emoji;
    });

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      picker.togglePicker(button);
    });
  }
```

every thing worked fine when I test my app on linux, windows 10, and mac, but when I test on windows 7 it is look like this
[image]

please help me how can I make this plugin to support windows 7 Or any suggestion to any MIT plugin support all Operating systems.

thank you

Comment: What browser are you using for testing it on Wndows 7? Is it updated? Are you using Internet Explorer? It seems that Internet Explorer is not supported.

Comment: @AntonioVida yes I know that internet explorer is not supported, I used the latest version of chrome

Comment: I think the issue is related to the support of emojis in a older operating system. Only  newer operating system have support for all the emojis you would expect. A few emojis was released as part of different Unicode versions after the relase of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *issue related to the support of emojis in a older operating system*. Only newer operating system have support for all the emojis you would expect.

A few emojis was released as part of different Unicode versions after the release of Windows 7.

It may help to fix that to use some third-party, but I don't really think it's possible to fix all the missing emojis. For example, Windows 7 has update ([KB2729094](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30566)) which provides unicode emoji support (An update for the [Segoe UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/typography/font-list/segoe-ui)). However, some of new emojis are still missing and they are in black and white.